# Flutter[desktop]: how to get input from physical keyboard without textfield?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I have been working on Flutter desktop and stuck at the point where I need to get a keyboard key input, without TextField, like in any desktop application or game. How can I work with input streams without TextFields?

Comment: Is the keyboard visible at that point?

Answer (score 2):

You want a [RawKeyboardListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html).

An important caveat is that desktop support for that is still a work in progress; on Linux and Windows you'll currently get an Android key event that's only partially populated.